# Neo4j find shortest path but exclude a path

Tags: graph, neo4j

For a school assignment I am trying to understand how Neo4j works this far I have been able to understand most of it but for some reason am not able to exclude a path.

I made a test assignment being made of roads that could be used from like City -> City. Now I want to exclude a path like in the following situation:

"Find all the routes from Utrecht to Rotterdam that do not take Gouda in the route"

I came up with a number of solutions but they do not work and the closest I came was finding all the paths including the Gouda path with the following code

```
MATCH (Utrecht {Naam:"Utrecht"}), (Stad)-[:CONNECTIE_MET]->(Rotterdam:Stad{Naam:"Rotterdam"}), 
p = allShortestPaths( (Utrecht)-[:CONNECTIE_MET*..5]-(Rotterdam))
WHERE NOT(Stad.Naam='Gouda')
RETURN p,Utrecht
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried several things but it doesn't work and code from other posts do not seem to work for this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortest path won't answer your question of "find all routes..." because it will not include routes that are longer than the shortest path. Aside from this, your question is something that shortest path can't handle well because it will find the shortest path first and then apply the filter, possibly throwing out the shortest path and giving you no results, whereas most users want to find the shortest path with the filter applied. This might get you started, though:

```
MATCH p = (:Stad {Naam:"Utrecht"})-[:CONNECTIE_MET*..5]->(:Stad {Naam:"Rotterdam"})
WHERE NONE(x IN NODES(p) WHERE x.Naam = "Gouda")
RETURN p;
```

Comment: thanks this helps alot! and definitly gives me other routes to work with ! :)